# How can I cancel the next 'then' in a Promise when a React component is unmounted/reused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to cancel a promise when a React component is unmounted/reused. Right now I am facing a issue which I can better explain in a little graph below:

** The Promise must finish (executes an AJAX requests and updates the redux store accordingly)

Component is created => Mounted => _onClick() fired => Promise starts => Component gets unmounted but is recycled => Promise finished => calls setState() in the recycled component and rerenders with the wrong state from the previous component.

How can I cancel/interrupt/stop the next 'then' but still execute the Promise?

```
...
    _onClick() {
        let dispatch = this.props.dispatch;

        if (!this.state.on) {
            API.On(dispatch, this.props.id).then(() => {
                this.setState({
                    on: true,
                })
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.setState({
                    on: false,
                })
            });
        } else {
            API.Off(dispatch, this.props.id).then(() => {
                this.setState({
                    on: false,
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.setState({
                    on: true,
                })
            })
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: What is causing your component to be unmounted?

Comment: @jmargolisvt the component is inside a list. E.g: 2 components in a list, first 1 gets removed, second one gets moved to the top. The promise from the first 1 is then gets called inside the second component

Answer (score -2):

What I'd do here is just add a conditional to the body of the promise that sets the state. You can use React's lifecycle hooks in order to keep track of whether the element is currently in the DOM or not.

Here's a quick example of a component that keeps track of whether it is mounted or not:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<p>hello</p>);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.mounted = true
    console.log(`mounted: ${this.mounted}`)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.mounted = false
    console.log(`mounted: ${this.mounted}`)
  }
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/jenius/pen/MmjPJV

---

Based on this, you should be able to add a simple if/else inside your promise handler to solve your issue!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jeff. This solves the issue if the component is unmounted, except not if it is recycled

Comment: Using this.mounted is an antipattern, see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html